# How to transpose non-unique variables in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have a dataset which looks like this:

| ObjectID | Factor1 | Factor 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0 |
| 1 | B | 0 |
| 1 | C | 1 |
| 2 | D | 0 |
| 2 | E | 0 |
| 3 | F | 0 |

I want to transpose factor1 and factor2 together, so that I get something like this:

| ObjectID | Factor1Col1 | Factor1Col2 | Factor1Col3 | Factor2Col1 | Factor2Col2 | Factor2Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | C | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | D | E |  | 0 | 0 |  |
| 3 | F |  |  | 0 |  |  |

What is the best way to do this in SAS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are both FACTOR1 and FACTOR2 character variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transpose each of the two columns from long format to wide format and then merge the results:

```
proc transpose data=in_dset out=temp1 prefix=Factor1Col;
   by objectid;
   var factor1;
run;

proc transpose data=in_dset out=temp2 prefix=Factor2Col;
   by objectid;
   var factor2;
run;

data final;
   merge temp1(drop=_name_) temp2(drop=_name_);
   by objectid;
run;
```

Comment: If performance is super important, you might work with one `proc transpose' and a more complex merge statement `merge temp(where=(_name_=Factor1) rename=(Col1=Factor1Col1 ...))`, but you will need some macro coding to automate this.